# In Python multiprocessing. Pool, how to get the print result in the subprocess

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

The thing is that:

```
def main_fun(x):
    ...
    print(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool(5) as pool:
        pool.map(main_fun,range(10000))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

My question is that: if I run the code on my own computer, it output subprocess print result. But when I submit it as  a job to the cluster, I could not see the print result until the whole programs finished. How could I fix it? By the way, the cluster uses the Slurm.

Comment: Can you try doing `pinrt(x, flush = True)`, i.e. add `flush` param.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing `print(x, flush = True)` instead of just `print(x)`.

Flush-variant of call does immediate flush of buffers so that printing is seen right away. While non-flush variant may keep string inside buffer until later time when it is flushed to screen.

Also always do `pool.close()` and `pool.join()` inside `with` block (at the end), not out-side like you did. For the case of just `.map()` function it doesn't matter, because it is blocking call, but for some other cases it is important to close/join inside `with` block.

Comment: @master_zhen Also notice, I just updated my answer with instructions regarding close/join, it is important for some of cases.

Comment: The paragraph about `pool.close()` and `pool.join()` sounds dubious. The [documentation example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) does not do that and it seems sensible that the `with` (context manager) already handles that for us.